# Socket address already in use - Forgot SO_REUSEADDR at first

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Please help,

At first, I created a socket and bound it to address without SO_REUSEADDR.

Then, my program crashed (not properly closing socket)

Next, I run it again and "Address already in use" is returned from bind()

I tried to modify source code to use SO_REUSEADDR but it is no-use.

Now, I couldn't run bind again (the server can't be rebooted)

Comment: If no one adds a useful answer in 4 minutes, just try again and it should work :)

Comment: Also, some answers at http://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait can be useful.

Comment: The `SO_REUSEADDR` flag have to be set for the socket that now is in the [`TIME_WAIT` state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg). So all you can do is wait for the timeout, and remember to set the flag in your program so it won't happen again.

Comment: You modified your source code wrongly. Show the code that creates the socket and sets SO_REUSEADDR.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't believe that's correct for TCP. I suspect he just hasn't set SO_REUSEADDR *before* calling bind().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to wait until the session times out, then it will be deleted completely.

When a session shuts down in a "dirty" manner, you can't reuse that address again (assuming you're not using SO_REUSEADDR) for twice the maximum segment lifetime - typically this is about four minutes for regular network hardware though it actually depends on the properties of the medium (satellites may have a larger MSL for example).

This is to ensure that any packets still in transition don't arrive and screw up your sequencing on the new session.