# Can't connect Java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to connect two simple Java sockets but whatever port number I type I get the same error : Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Now I found I way around the problem by using using 0 as an argument to the ServerSocket constructor and then calling the getLocalPort method to get the first available port and then pass it to my client class in the Socket constructor as an argument.

So, in NetBeans IDE, I first run the server, get the available port from the console, copy the number and manually enter it to the Socket constructor as the second argument after "localhost" and run the client.

Now the expected output would be "Connected" as the server has accepted the client, but instead, I get the available port number incremented by 1.

Why is this happening? It seems that when I click run in my client.java file I start the server again instead of the client.

sever.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(58801);/I manually add the available port number here 

        System.out.println(s1.getLocalPort());

        Socket ss = s1.accept();

        System.out.println("Client connected");

    }

}
```

client.java :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;


public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 58801); // I here manually add the available port number 

    }

}
```

Comment: You use `0`, as a port in `ServerSocket(0);`, and that port is reserved, you can't use it.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Oh, I just made the mistake of leaving it 0, I do pass the available port number there as well and I always get the same error : Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Comment: This works fine. I can't reproduce the problem. Most likely, you use that port.. check by `netstat`.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, as long as I run the server before the client.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I just did. I saw the used ports at localhost and the just incremented the last used one by 1... I get the same error. 

Also, when I click run on the client.java, I get the output as a port number, but my client class does not have any output methods such as System.out.println. Really weird.

Comment: @LukaJović It makes perfect sense to get the println output when the client connects. It releases the server from waiting on the accept and then it prints. You may be running both programs on the same screen console, for example by launching them both from the IDE.

Comment: You print `System.out.println(s1.getLocalPort());` on your server side.. please pay attention and clarify what exactly does not work and how. Include the log message you get as error. See the `netstat` and find the process that may use your IP.

Comment: @GonenI You're right. By pressing the run button in NetBeans I'm actually running the same file over again. I just right clicked on the client, selected run and I got the desired result. Thank you.

Comment: When testing server code you'll often shut things down in a "dirty" manner, in which case the server socket is left in a wait state for a few minutes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621419/238704) answer. One solution is to use the [option SO_REUSEADDR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html#SO_REUSEADDR) in the `setOption` call to the server socket.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat belated answer, after the OP already figured it out:

One possible cause is running the server twice by mistake in the IDE. The first run grabs the port, the second run of the server will find that port already in use and generate the error.

Answer (score 0):

An example of Server client socket:

Server class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class GreetServer {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String greeting = in.readLine();
        if ("hello server".equals(greeting)) {
            out.println("hello client");
        } else {
            out.println("unrecognised greeting");
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GreetServer server = new GreetServer();
        server.start(6666);
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class GreetClient {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public void startConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public String sendMessage(String msg) throws IOException {
        out.println(msg);
        String resp = in.readLine();
        return resp;
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GreetClient client = new GreetClient();
        client.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 6666);

        String response = client.sendMessage("hello server");
        System.out.println("Response from server: " + response);
    }
}
```

Example response:

```
Response from server: hello client
```

Comment: There is no answer here to the OP's question "Why is this happening?"